# Delete and update a SQL table in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working with MVC5.  I have a working table of SQL data in Index.cshtml.

I have a simple SQL table consisting of five element, testID is the primary key with no errors.

I am trying to do here is delete a row of data and have it update the SQL table.

Index.cshtml

```
<center>
<table>
    <tr><td colspan="5" align="center"><br /><br /><h1>Table1 Printout</h1></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="center">testID</td><td align="center">datetime</td><td align="center">col1</td><td align="center">col2</td><td align="center">col3</td><td></td></tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.thistable)
    {
        <tr><td>@item.testID</td><td>@item.datetime</td><td>@item.col1</td><td>@item.col2</td><td>@item.col3</td><td><form action="@Url.Action("Delete", new{ testID = @item.testID})" method="delete"><input type="submit" value="Delete" /></form></td></tr>
    }
</table>
</center>
```

HomeController.cs

```
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        Table1.Remove(Table1.SingleOrDefault(o => o.testID == id));
        return RedirectToAction("uvm");
    }
```

Class.cs

```
public class Table1
{
    [Key]
    public int testID { get; set; }
    public string datetime { get; set; }
    public string col1 { get; set; }
    public string col2 { get; set; }
    public string col3 { get; set; }
}
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string errorcode { get; set; }
    public List<Table1> thistable { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `SaveChanges()` method to replicate changes to database which you have made in model.
Also you need to make changes to entities in your `DbContext`.

```
Entities ent = new Entities();    //This is name of DbConetxt Class
ent.Table1.Remove(ent.Table1.SingleOrDefault(o => o.testID == id));
ent.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I am also having trouble with "Remove" and "SingleOrDefault" MVC5 is having trouble with these.

Comment: Table1 does not contain the definition for either Remove or SingleOrDefault.  How do you define them in Table1?

Comment: That corrected the Remove and Single... but now Table1 is undefined.

Comment: So your table name will be something else. What is name of table in DB ?